# What am I iterating over?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I am practicing pandas dataframes and I'm confused about one thing since I'm still a newbie at Python coming from a strong Java, C family background.

```
for i in dataframe1.columns:
    dataframe1[i] = np.where(dataframe1[i] == 0, np.nan, dataframe1[i])
```

I am confused with what I am iterating over? As I take it, dataframe1.columns would return the column names or columns objects (however it's done in Python) of the dataframe.
So when using the where() function for the condition, dataframe1[i] == 0 wouldn't that just check if the column name (whether in string format or object format) == 0 or not? Or does python implicitly iterate through the values within each column even though it's not explicitly specified so in code?

Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried checking `type(dataframe1.columns)`? Try printing its type and its value.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, anyway? You should always take a step back and reconsider your approach if you find yourself iterating over a dataframe.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what am I checking for using the type() function?

Comment: I am trying to change the value of the elements in each cell to np.nan if their value is 0. As you can see from my where function.

Comment: The type of the object. You asked "what am I iterating over?" -- answer is a list. Specifically a list of strings, the names of the columns in the dataframe.

Comment: I recommend trying to get into the habit of checking documentation as well as using the built-in `help()`, `dir()`, and `type()` functions whenever you get confused about what you're doing.

Comment: For changing `0` to `NaN` you can use `pd.DataFrame.replace`

Comment: Ok got it. 

Let's say we have column names as "fruits", "veggies", "flowers", "meat" and "spices".
So when dataframe1.columns returns a list of strings (which would be the aforementioned column names) and when I use the where() function, wouldn't dataframe1[i] == 0 simply just check if the string values viz "fruits", "veggies", "flowers", "meat" and "spices" == 0? 

Wouldn't that just return false since a string value cannot be equal to a integer value? Or does the string name correspond to the name of the list variable containing the values within that column? I'm confused.

Comment: No, the loop `for i in dataframe1.columns` is iterating over a list of the column names as strings. The loop variable takes each value of that list, one at a time. Try printing the loop variable `i`. It's just a string. But `dataframe1[i]` is NOT a string.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @ddejohn,

```
data = [
         ['fruit', 'veggies', 0], 
         ['0', 0, 'spices']
        ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df


    col1    col2      col3
0   fruit   veggies      0
1      0         0    spices
```

using replace will give:

```
new_df=df.replace(0,np.nan)
new_df

    str1    str2     str3
0   fruit   veggies  NaN
1   0         NaN    spices
```

Notice that it didn't switch the zero in the first column because it is a string of zero, not an actual zero.